# Looking for the Swarm code that initiates token addresses on the web

Tags: web3js, swarm

When I go to swarm website, the site next steps prompts and issues me an address. I am curious just how this works even though I don't have an account yet. Is my address then the account no? or does it use some sort of session state/cookies to identify me.

If anyone can point me to the web3.js API or code that does this feature, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks